# Compare an object type with string in jinja

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

I am making a project in djnago.
I am having a condition in jinja html template where a comparision is not running correctly.Even through  there values are same .

**part of code which is not working:-**

```
{%if user_obj.status =='Online'%}
<p>Working</p>
{%endif%}
```

**Profile Model:-** which i am used in comparison

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    username=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
```

i think they are of different type that's why they are not working.But how can i make them working.

Comment: Try printing user_obj.status to see what the value is

Comment: it's printing the same "Online"

Comment: is status an FK to another table?

Comment: @at14 Nope.See i have added Profile model which i used

Comment: Just guessing, but try user_obj.status.status == 'Online'

Comment: Not working.They are of different types.So we must to something else